# angular.injector array value not returning current values

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my addChore function I display the length of the array that is being added to.  Then later in the code I'm trying to get the choreList.chore array but I'm noticing that it doesn't contain all the elements that I just added.

Is there something I'm missing to get the to operate correctly?

This is my entire service that I'm using:

```
  myapp.service('myService', function () {

  var choreList = this;
  choreList.chore = [{ name: 'Take out Trash', frequency: 'Sundays', allowance: '$0.25', id: 0 },
                     { name: 'Unload Dishwasher', frequency: 'Fridays', allowance: 'Free', id: 1 }];

  var familyList = this;
  familyList.people = [
    { name: 'Johnny', dob: '01/01/2005', cell: '3035551212', carrier: 'ATT', email: 'liljohnny@test.com', active: true, personId: 0 },
    { name: 'Susie', dob: '03/01/2005', cell: '3035551313', carrier: 'SPRINT', email: 'susieq@test.com', active: true, personId: 1 }];

  choreList.addChore = function () {
      choreList.chore.push({
          name: choreList.inputChore, frequency: $('#inputFrequency').val(),
          allowance: $('#inputAllowance').val(), id: choreList.chore.length
      });

      choreList.inputChore = '';
      $('#inputFrequency').val('Mondays');
      $('#inputAllowance').val('Free');
      alert(choreList.chore.length);
  };

  this.returnChoreList = function () {
      return choreList.chore;
  }

  this.returnFamilyList = function () {
      return familyList.people;
  }

  familyList.addPerson = function () {
      //alert(familyList.inputName + ', ' + familyList.inputBirthday + ', ' + familyList.inputCellPhone, + ', ' + familyList.inputCarrier + ', ' + familyList.inputEmail);
      familyList.people.push({
          name: familyList.inputName, dob: familyList.inputBirthday,
          cell: familyList.inputCellPhone, carrier: familyList.inputCarrier,
          email: familyList.inputEmail, active: true, personId: familyList.people.length + 1
      });

      familyList.inputName = '';
      familyList.inputDOB = '';
      familyList.inputCellPhone = '';
      familyList.inputCarrier = 0;
      familyList.inputEmail = '';
      familyList.active = true;
  };

  });
```

When I get the length after I add to the choreList.chore I get the initial 2 items + the new one that I'm adding (so 3 for this example).

But when I call the returnChoreList function I only get 2 (the initial 2 records).

Is there a different way to do this?

This is how I'm calling to get the array in jQuery:

```
 $(document).on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', 'input[id^="chk"]', function (event, state) {
  var clistArr;
  clistArr = angular.injector(['ng', 'familyApp']).get("myService").returnChoreList();
  alert(clistArr.length);
});
```

**Update:**
Based off of a plunkr that I modified from @camden_kid I think it is in the `angular.injector` statement:

http://plnkr.co/edit/fxOaJdsVk9Tb7rrEwPrB?p=preview

As I'm getting similar behavior in the plunkr as I am with my code.

**Update #2:**

Thanks to Camden_kid for getting me this far...

I think I've narrowed it down to multiple service calls because of my mixing with jQuery and Angular.

I have this code that allows me to capture when I interact with the dynamic switches that get generated when I add chores and people.

```
$(document).on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', 'input[id^="chk"]', function (event, state) {
```

It is in between here that I'm also calling this:

```
    var clistArr;
    clistArr = angular.injector(['ng', 'familyApp']).get("myService").returnChoreList();
```

Based off of what Camden_kid said, I can not have multiple instances of "myService".  This line effectively gets regenerated every time for each person/chore combo.

Is there anyway to have 1 reference of "myService" but be able to call the returnChoreList function?

Comment: @camden_kid well I only tested it when adding a new item.  It went from 3 to 2.

Comment: @camden_kid - I have no idea.  I got that code from an example.  It returns the array.  But just the originally loaded values.  Not any new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a simplified app based on your code that works fine - [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6D1UbSjLNhQ8tb8hcaNY?p=preview)

JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', ["$scope", 'myService', function($scope, myService){
  var vm = this;
  vm.myService = myService;
}]);

app.service('myService', function () {
  var choreList = this;
  choreList.chore = [];

  choreList.addChore = function () {
    choreList.chore.push({a: 1});
    alert(choreList.chore.length);
  };

  this.returnChoreList = function () {
      alert(choreList.chore.length);
      return choreList.chore;
  }
});
```

Markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
  <button ng-click="vm.myService.addChore()">Add</button>
  <button ng-click="vm.myService.returnChoreList()">Return</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit1: regarding your updated question and comments this line:

```
angular.injector(['ng', 'familyApp']).get("myService")
```

is returning a new copy of the service and so the array is always the default length.

Edit2: here's a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aV6tVkx1CkNDQvyrfZl2?p=preview) based on your Plunker. :-)

Comment: I updated my question to also show that I'm using a angular-injector line in jQuery to get the array.

Comment: when I added the injector code I was able to call the function but the array length returned 0...  Very similar behavior.  Here is the forked version of that plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/fxOaJdsVk9Tb7rrEwPrB?p=preview

Comment: that makes sense.  Is there anyway I can do it they way I was trying to, because in my code there are lots of buttons that can be pressed.  Some are using Angular and this one happens to be using jQuery. I'm hoping is away to get what is currently available.  Just wondering.

Comment: it does.  I just have to spend more time with this knowledge and the code that I wrote.  Hopefully tonight I'll be able to re-wire it and get it working.

Comment: Yeah because I'm using a jQuery calendar, I kind of have no choice. I do have 1 final puzzle piece. It appears that the multiple instances is coming from this line in my jQuery: $(document).on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', 'input[id^="chk"]', function (event, state) { It is in this code that I'm calling my injector. Is there anyway I can just have 1 service reference but be able to call a function that returns the list of chores?   I updated the question to try to make it a little more clear.

Comment: @webdad3 My last working Plunker shows you how to have just one service so then you just need to have **var clistArr = myService.returnChoreList();** as your regenerated line. Is that not possible?

Comment: I converted all my code to using a directive instead and that worked better.  Thank you for your help.  Your answer actually helped me a lot in writing the directive code.

Comment: @webdad3 Excellent news. :-)